# Dynamic class definition with block

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

So I've got this situation where I want to define a bunch of classes programatically. The method I am using below works fine, except for the fact that the 3rd-party class I am inheriting from here doesn't like the fact that the class is defined anonymously (basically, it doesn't have the information it needs, ie. the class name, in the 'inherited' hook, before I get a chance to set the anonymous class to a constant).

```
['one', 'two', 'three'].each do |model|
    cls = Class.new(ThirdPartyClass) do
        define_method :model do
            model
        end
    end
    ThirdPartyClass.const_set(model.capitalize, cls)
end
```

I could simply use an eval and define the class something like:

```
['one', 'two', 'three'].each do |model|
    eval "class ThirdPartyClass::#{model.capitalize} < ThirdPartyClass; ...; end"
end
```

but I don't like it because then it's messy string interpolation. The block based method seems 'nicer', aesthetically-speaking.

Is there any way I can define that class non-anonymously (ie. with a name right from the beginning) using a block-based syntax, or am I doomed to stay in the land of eval's messy string inputs?

Comment: It is strange that you want a class to be within the name space of and be a subclass of the same class.

Comment: True, but the namespace thing is orthogonal to this particular problem (at least I think so). If you're curious, I'm using the classy_enum gem, and by convention of that gem, the enum values must be within the namespace of the main enum class. It produces an enum syntax somewhat similar to that in other languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Class#inherited` callback gets invoked when the class is created.  When instantiating an anonymous class, this will always be before the class can be assigned to constant, assigning it a name. I can't see any way to work around this.  You might *minimize* the amount of code in the string eval by using eval to create an empty class using the special class syntax that makes the name visible before `inherited`, then follow up with class_eval in block form to define your methods.

```
class Super
  def self.inherited(child)
    puts "#{self.name} inherited by #{child.inspect} named '#{child.name}'"
  end
end

# Your way, inherited can't see name
['one', 'two', 'three'].each do |model|
  klassname = model.capitalize
  klass = Class.new(Super) do
    puts "defining #{model} inheriting from Super"
    define_method :model do
      model
    end
  end
  Super.const_set(klassname, klass)
end

# this way inherited sees name because we use special class definition syntax in minimal string eval
['four', 'five', 'six'].each do |model|
  klassname = model.capitalize

  eval %Q{
    class Super::#{klassname} < Super
      puts %Q[defining Super::#{klassname} inheriting from Super]
    end
  }

  Super.const_get(klassname).class_eval do
    puts "defining methods for Super::#{klassname} inheriting from Super"
    define_method :model do
      model
    end
  end
end

# produces:
Super inherited by #<Class:0x0000010084c988> named ''
defining one inheriting from Super
Super inherited by #<Class:0x0000010084c640> named ''
defining two inheriting from Super
Super inherited by #<Class:0x0000010084c320> named ''
defining three inheriting from Super
Super inherited by Super::Four named 'Super::Four'
defining Super::Four inheriting from Super
defining methods for Super::Four inheriting from Super
Super inherited by Super::Five named 'Super::Five'
defining Super::Five inheriting from Super
defining methods for Super::Five inheriting from Super
Super inherited by Super::Six named 'Super::Six'
defining Super::Six inheriting from Super
defining methods for Super::Six inheriting from Super
```